# How do I print out ForeignKey models that are linked to a specific model in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am using a django model to save user uploaded images. I want each image to be stored in the productimage model that is a foreign key model to the product model which is a foreign key model to the user model. What I mean is:

User -----> Product ------> Productimage

I am using for loops to print out all of a users products from the product model. Then for each product in the product model the productimage ForeignKey models linked to that particular product model should be printed out. However when I return the productimage model it returns all the productimage models instead of only the ones linked to that particular product model.

To futher clarify my question what I mean is that let's say for ProductA, print out all the Productimages attatched to ProductA but instead of printing all of them out it's printing out all the Productimages regardless of which Product model they are linked to.

```
models.py:
  class product(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     product_title =  models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
     product_price =  models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
     product_description =  models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)

 class productimage(models.Model):
     product = models.ForeignKey(product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     product_images = models.FileField(blank=True)


views.py:
 def products(request):
     template = loader.get_template("main/products.html")
     products = request.user.product_set.all()
     for product in products:
         productsimages = product.productimage_set.all()
         for productimage in productsimages:
             imageurl = productimage.product_images.url
     context = {
         "products" : products,
         "productsimages" : productsimages,
         "imageurl" : imageurl,
         }
     return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))




 Html template:
   <div  id="noproducts">
   <!-- <img class="options" src="/static/main/images/box2.png"/>
   <h2>It seems like you don't have any products</h2> -->
   {% for product in products %}
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3" id="holla">
       <div id="imgcontainer">
         <img id="img" src="{{ imageurl }}">
       </div>
       <p>{{ product.product_title }}</p>
       <p>₦{{ product.product_price }}</p>
       <p>{{ product.product_description }}</p>
   </div>
   {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

Comment: You are repeatedly overwritting productimages and imageurl in the for loops. So in the context, the products will have all the user products, productsimages will have the productimage instances of the last product and imageurl will have the url of last productimage of the last product... which doesn't make sense. Instead in the view, you must query the user products, prefetch the productimages and use the for loop in the template.

Comment: Can you explain to me how to do this?

Comment: try the code I have posted

Comment: Also I suggest you add a related_name="images" in the product field and rename the productimages to 'path' so that you will get a more meaningful query route such as... for image in product.images.all ... and then inside the forloop, it would be image.path.url. Best of luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another loop inside your product to show its images..

```
{% for product in products %}
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3" id="holla">
       <div id="imgcontainer">
         {%for product_image in product.productimage_set.all %}
           <img id="img" src="{{ product_image.product_images.url }}">
         {% endfor %}
       </div>
       <p>{{ product.product_title }}</p>
       <p>₦{{ product.product_price }}</p>
       <p>{{ product.product_description }}</p>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Oh and one last thing, how do I make it print out only the first picture for each productimage of a product?

Comment: you dont need the second forloop in that case.. after "<div id="imgcontainer"> "... add <img id="img" src="{{ product.productimage_set.first.product_images.url }}">

Answer (score 2):

inside the forloop for products you can use :

```
{% for product in products %}
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3" id="holla">

    {% for p_img in product.productsimages_set.all %}

    <img src="{{ p_img.product_images.url }}">

    {% endfor %}
       <p>{{ product.product_title }}</p>
       <p>₦{{ product.product_price }}</p>
       <p>{{ product.product_description }}</p>
   </div>
   {% endfor %}
```

and delete the productimages from context

if still no images shown, check in your console if those img tags are displayed, if yes, your lookup for the images isn't correct, but thats another question